# postgresql triggers: How to get a trigger when table is not getting new data

Tags: postgresql, triggers, cron

I have a remote program which keeps inserting new row every second in a table of postgresql db.

Sometimes the program stops inserting new row, due to some wifi problem. At that time, is there a way i can get some notification when no new row is added in last 10 seconds.

Currently I run a cron job every sec, which keeps checking the recent id from the table. If recent id does not change after 10s then I create notification.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think, the cronjob is your best bet.
There is no AFTER NOTHING HAPPENS in the CREATE TRIGGER syntax ;)

The other options you have is to move the job to the database using pg_cron or background worker. But I really think any of the two options (specially the second one) is complicating things for no gain.